# React Native <Image> not working in Android

Tags: android, react-native

- The following code works perfectly on iOS.
- In fact, the below code is copied verbatim from the iOS one.
- I made sure that react-native was loading changes into my app properly by making other changes and loading them into the app.
- Nonetheless, the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ulyJ.jpg simply doesn't display in Android.
- **Update**: I tried "Inspect Element" and I can see the Image on the screen, however, it's a blank box.

I run the server like this

```
react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And then I run these every time I change the code

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
react-native run-android
```

Source code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;
var MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA = [
  {title: 'Title', year: '2015', posters: {thumbnail: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ulyJ.jpg'}},
];

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var movie = MOCKED_MOVIES_DATA[0];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
        <Text>{movie.year}</Text>
        <Image
          source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: any luck.. is it working now??. as I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I would be sure to review your index.android.js file and ensure that you are properly including all component dependencies, that is the only thing that would prevent the same code from acting different on a cross-platform component like Image.